# How to add Fade-out and Fade-in Effects by convert command?

Tags: convert, imagemagick

`convert` command can make the mpeg video from the several pictures.

For example:

```
convert -delay 300 *.png test.mpg
```

Well, is it possible to add Fade-out and Fade-in effects into the mpeg video by using `convert` ?

If it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: Haven't got the time to turn this into a full answer, but I'm fairly certain that you can overlay a colored rectangle over the image, and adjust its opacity. That would give you the individual frames. Combining all of these into a single image will probably require some shell scripting, and might even need files for the intermediate images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally stick to video tools for generating video. Imagemagick is pretty awesome but it's no ffmpeg. ffmpeg (or avconv as it's now known) can handle both frame-stitching and [fade options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#fade) in one go:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -b 500000 -i frame%05d.png -vf fade=out:155:45 output.mp4
```

If you're not familiar with ffmpeg, here's a quick translation of that command:

- 24fps
- ~500kbps bitrate
- Uses all images called frame{00000..99999}.png
- starts fading out at at frame 155 with a fade duration of 45 frames
- outputs to output.mp4

ffmpeg also gives you a ton of options about handling audio, codecs, containers, etc that Imagemagick wont, but I'm leaving that well alone. Have a play.

**Edit:** I was originally making this up on the spot but I can confirm that this works just as expected/described.

Comment: It seems that it is difficult only with `convert` command.  But, I didn't know that it was possible by using ffmpeg. Thank you for the information.